# Why did God change Saul's mind immediately after Samuel spoke to him which was prior to the events mentioned in 1 Samuel 10?

Tags: prophecy, 1-samuel, saul

After Samuel had anointed Saul it is said God changed his mind which seems to be contrary to what  Samuel had told Saul.

1 Samuel 10:9 NIV

***9 As Saul turned to leave Samuel, God changed Saul’s heart, and all these signs were fulfilled that day***.

But Samuel had mentioned a couple of events that will take place prior to this happening,

The listed events are:

*Saul will meet two men who will disclose that the donkeys have been found(1 Samuel 10:1-2)

*Then he will meet three men going to Bethel who will give them two loaves of bread(1 Samuel 10:3-4)

*After that he will meet a procession of prophets and will prophesy(1 Samuel 10:5-7)

*Finally he will be changed into another man(1 Samuel 10:6-7)

It seems the order of events did not unfold the way Samuel had projected

How can the above events be understood?

Answer (score 1):

1 Samuel 10:

> 9 As Saul turned to leave Samuel, **God changed Saul’s heart**, and all these signs were fulfilled that day.

Why did God change Saul's mind immediately after Samuel spoke to him?

God changed Saul's heart, not mind.
After God had changed Saul's heart,

1. Saul will meet two men who will disclose that the donkeys have been found(1 Samuel 10:1-2)
2. Then he will meet three men going to Bethel who will give them two loaves of bread(1 Samuel 10:3-4)
3. After that he will meet a procession of prophets and will prophesy(1 Samuel 10:5-7)
4. Finally he will be changed into another man(1 Samuel 10:6-7)

God changed Saul's heart, then turned him into another man. It is logical.